# Coupling of silyl imine and aldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

LDA is a strong base and probably deprotonates somewhere which I'm not sure about. It I would to make a guess it would probably be beta to the imine. This is following by nucleophilic attack of the carboanion onto the use of the second reagent Pr-CHO to generate an alcohol. But I'm not sure the purpose of the 3rd reagent (oxalic acid).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a Peterson olefination, specifically this one is from the synthesis of Roseophilin published in *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* (**2001**) *123* 8509. The LDA deprotonates next to the silicon as both it and the adjacent imine stabilise the anion.

The Wikipedia page gives a good summary of the mechanism and why an acidic work up is used in this case to give the required double bond geometry ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson_olefination)).

> [image]

(Image from [www.chem.wisc.edu](https://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/OrgMet/silicon%7B05%7D.htm))

Answer (score 3):

@Waylander has nailed it.

But, an interesting part of mechanism is that it proceeds via chair form of six membered transition state as shown [here](https://www.synarchive.com/named-reactions/Peterson-Olefination). Among two possible transition states, only one is *favored*. The other transition state, *disfavored* has isopropyl group (from LDA) and trimethylsilyl group in *axial* positions leading to 1,3 diaxial repulsions (shown in the figure below).

[image]

[image]

[source](https://www.synarchive.com/named-reactions/Peterson-Olefination)

In this mechanism, the starting material is an ester. You could use starting material in the post instead.